# Full outer joins or Union . which is faster ( My table has a million rows )

Tags: oracle, performance, join

I have to join 3 tables to retrieve data and looks like full outer join is a potential solution but during my try it took more than a hour to execute the query .

Any alternatives would be helpful .

thank you.

Comment: MySQL does not support full outer joins

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag because it does not support `full join`.  You should probably delete this question and ask another question with sample data and queries.

Comment: we need table strucutres, table sizes(e.g. the number of rows), what did u so far and its explain plan at least

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your query looks like however, add indexes on the table if these tables are newly being created.

However, answering your question using UNION ALL will be faster, as it simply passes the first SELECT statement, and then parses the second SELECT statement and adds the results to the end of the output table. Even a Normal UNION is faster than a join.

The UNION's will make better use of indexes which could result in a faster query.